# PHP validate if duplicate char "?"

Tags: php, url

I have URL parameter like this: `http://localhost/project-mini-framework/public/Home/_list?page=2?page=3`

How to validate if i have duplicate char "?" in PHP code.

terima kasih

Comment: you are formatting your url badly. instead of checking  duplicate `?` try to correct URL formatting code to get correct URL format like either page=2 or page=3 not both at the same time

Comment: Simple fact is that , After fist "?"  everything will be marked as query string.  Quoting from wiki "The first question mark is used as a separator, and is not part of the query string."  Just for the answer , if you do $_GET['page']   in php side , you will get "2?page=3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will echo a count of the ?s in the string ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)). So correctly formatted will return 1, incorrectly more than 1. You can then use to validate as you wish by passing the output of the function to an if statement.

```
echo substr_count('http://localhost/project-mini-framework/public/Home/_list?page=2?page=3', '?');
```